# CKEditor trims whitespace in li

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

When I edit some HTML that contains trailing whitespace in a `li`, it gets trimmed by CKEditor.

I made an example here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/y2NFXtOvS9A52ZKYcA4M?p=preview

When you setData with trailing whitespace and then getData, the whitespace survives, but after a change (even if you undo it) it's missing. 
This is not specific to the angular-ckeditor-wrapper this example uses.
Why is that and how can I prevent it?

Also I can see that the double whitespace is normalized to one. That is HTML standard for display in the browser, but CKEDitor seems to keep this in getData. is there a way around this?

Comment: Hey, you might want to have a look at the answer here, it might give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44694324/1010492