# How to force CKEditor to preserve <br> tags

Tags: html, ckeditor

I am using the latest version of CKEditor (4.7 to date) with the standard package, and I want to be able to force it to preserve line break elements (`<br>`).

I have attempted to use the following config, without success:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('ck', {
    allowedContent: true,
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
});
```

As you can see [in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/922tL76e/), when you open Source mode, `<br>` tags have been replaced with a `&nbsp;`.

How do you achieve that?

Comment: The fiddle you provided replaces any break tags that exist outside of a `div` with nothing. This gives the appearance of those tags being replaced with the `&nbsp;`.  If you clear out the editor, add the same text, and click "Source", it will show that `<br>` tags are preserved.  In order to preserve `<br>` tags, they must be a child of a `<div>`. Is it possible for your application to reflect this?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not control which content is loaded into my CKEditor. The content is sent by my client, then loaded in the CKEditor, and he is expecting to get his formatting back...

Comment: check that , i think it's gonna help you : http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/trying-use-br-instead-p

Comment: @MOHAMMEDYASSINEChabli I'm already using this config. `br` tags are used, this is not the problem. The problem is that CKEditor removes some `br` tags and replace them with `&nbsp;`

Comment: are you using ckeditor in  a simple html , or  template engine ?

Comment: @MOHAMMEDYASSINEChabli see the JS fiddle in the question, nothing special: just adding the latest CKEditor to a dumb blank page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround (or at least partial workaround) was given on this [CKEditor ticket](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10146#comment:34), which forces the CKEditor to preserve `<br>` tags:

```
editor.on( 'pluginsLoaded', function( evt ){
    evt.editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules({
        elements :{
            br : function( element ) {          
                //if next element is BR or <!--cke_br_comment-->, ignore it.
                if( element && element.next && ( element.next.name == 'br' || element.next.value == 'cke_br_comment' ) ){
                    return;
                }else {
                    var comment = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.comment( 'cke_br_comment' );
                    comment.insertAfter( element ); 
                }
            }
        }
    });

evt.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
    comment : function( value, node ) {
        if( value.indexOf('cke_br_comment') >= 0 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

[Updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/922tL76e/4/).

EDIT: you might also want to check my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44694324/1010492) which may work better depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found a better answer which will work in more cases: introducing the "brangel" plugin:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('brangel', {
    init: function (editor) {
        editor.on('toHtml', function( evt ) {
            protectBRs(evt.data.dataValue);
        }, null, null, 5);
        editor.on('toHtml', function( evt ) {
            unprotectBRs(evt.data.dataValue);
        }, null, null, 14);
        editor.on('toDataFormat', function( evt ) {
            protectBRs(evt.data.dataValue);
        }, null, null, 5);
        editor.on('toDataFormat', function( evt ) {
            unprotectBRs(evt.data.dataValue);
        }, null, null, 14);

        function protectBRs(element) {
            var children = element.children;
            if (children) {
                for (var i = children.length; i--; ) {
                    var child = children[i];
                    if (child.name == "br") {
                        var placeholder = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text('{cke_br}');
                        placeholder.insertAfter(child);
                        child.remove();
                    } else {
                        protectBRs(child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function unprotectBRs(element) {
            var children = element.children;
            if (children) {
                for (var i = children.length; i--; ) {
                    var child = children[i];
                    if (child instanceof CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text && child.value === "{cke_br}") {
                        var br = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element('br');
                        br.insertAfter(child);
                        child.remove();
                    } else {
                        unprotectBRs(child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The idea is to save the `<br>` elements from destruction by temporarily replacing them with some placeholder text (`{cke_br}`) before the filtering phase of the CKEditor occurs (see [toDataFormat](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-toDataFormat) and [toHtml](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-toHtml) events), and then restore them back at the end. This is all transparent to the user.

[Updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/922tL76e/5/).

Answer (score 1):

The developers of CKeditor have reportedly told that **br to nbsp** auto conversion is not an issue but CKeditors ways of normalizing things.

It wont create any problem for you. So, you need not worry about your **br** tags being converted to **nbsp**
Go through the [following link](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12879) for more.

If you wish to remove the &nbsp from the source code, One way if to include the following :

```
 basicEntities: false,
 entities_additional: 'lt,gt,amp,apos,quot'
```

Comment: I understand that this is not an issue as the output looks the same. However if you consider that the message might be parsed from / back a third-party tool, this may become an issue. Consider updating your answer with one of the attempted workarounds in the tickets linked to the one you gave me.

Comment: hint: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10146#comment:34 seems to work pretty well. See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/922tL76e/3/ . If you're after the bounty, feel free to update your answer.

Comment: If you want to avoid the &nbsp; itself, you could simply use   basicEntities: false

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's &nbsp or a space. What I want is the BR to be preserved. Never mind, I'll the answer based on the workaround given in the ticket you gave me