# CKEditor removes <br> tags within <div> tags - how to stop this?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a document that contains:

```
<div><br/></div>
```

When CKEditor loads this (via calling setData()), and I examine the DOM with Chrome Developer Tools, it is retained.

However, if I call getData(false), I get back:

```
<div></div>
```

Even when I turn off filtering by setting allowedContent=true, don't disallow any content with disallowedContent, etc., the above still happens.

The only way I've found to stop this from happening is by changing the HTML to be:

```
<div data-cke-processor="off"><br/></div>
```

This works; but I can't make sure the incoming HTML is set up this way.

Does anyone know why CKEditor is doing this, even if I turn filtering completely off as in the above?

I'm using CKEditor 4.7 (the latest as of this date).

Comment: This may assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501658/how-to-force-ckeditor-to-preserve-br-tags

Comment: Thanks, @llarson ! Funny, I didn't see that thread when I searched relevant terms here - must have missed it!  I hope it helps solve my problem, though it does look like this bug isn't really "fixed" per se, despite the CKEditor bug report saying it's fixed.  I'll need to read through the StackOverflow discussion and the relevant ticket.